# Kafka Spark Streaming multiple aggregation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using Spark Kafka Integration 0.10 and I need two levels of aggregations on the stream:

1. The first one is per minute interval
2. The other is to sum on 15 minutes interval.

Also preference is to accumulate the one minute interval values and then reset it when 15 minute is over b/c 15 minute values should be persisted.

Having two `reduceByKeysByWindow`s on different sliding windows does not work as it gives `KafkaConcurrentModification` exception.

Comment: Please include code you use right now (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** It seems to work. Please provide an example that fails.

I am using Spark 2.0.2 (that was released [today](http://spark.apache.org/news/spark-2-0-2-released.html)).

My example is as follows (with some code removed for brevity):

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._

val dstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  preferredHosts,
  ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams, offsets))

def reduceFunc(v1: String, v2: String) = s"$v1 + $v2"
dstream.map { r =>
  println(s"value: ${r.value}")
  val Array(key, value) = r.value.split("\\s+")
  println(s">>> key = $key")
  println(s">>> value = $value")
  (key, value)
}.reduceByKeyAndWindow(
  reduceFunc, windowDuration = Seconds(30), slideDuration = Seconds(10))
  .print()

dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  // Get the offset ranges in the RDD
  val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
  for (o <- offsetRanges) {
    println(s"${o.topic} ${o.partition} offsets: ${o.fromOffset} to ${o.untilOffset}")
  }
}

ssc.start
```

What would you change to see the exception(s) you're experiencing?

The entire project is available as [spark-streaming-kafka-direct](https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/spark-workshop/tree/gh-pages/solutions/spark-streaming-kafka-direct).